# Not getting data sent from postman in server.js file from mutation

Tags: express, graphql, postman, graphql-js, prisma

I am using graphql, prisma & express to test simple query & mutation but when I am sending data from postman I am not getting the data sent from postman,
I am sending this mutation to graphql but inside server.js file

```
mutation{
    createUser(user_name:"test"){
        user_name
    }
}
```

, I am getting undefined,
In REST API you can use body parser to fix this for json, Is there anything like same to deal with query & mutaion of graphql with prisma & express

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const  express  = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');


const prisma = new PrismaClient();


const typeDefs = `
  type User {
    user_name: String
  }
  type Query {
    allUsers: [User!]!
  }
  type Mutation {
      createUser(user_name:String):User
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allUsers: () => {
        console.log(prisma)
      return prisma.user.findMany();
    }
  },
  Mutation:{
      createUser:async(user_name)=>{
        console.log(user_name)
          user={
              "user_name":user_name
          }
   
          const test= await prisma.user.create({ data: user })
          return test
      }
  }
};
 const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});
const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
}));
app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to your GraphQl query/mutation are passed through the second argument (typically defined as `args`) of your resolver. Update your `Mutation` like this

```js
Mutation: {
        createUser: async (parent, args, context) => {
            console.log(args.user_name);
            user = {
                user_name: args.user_name,
            };

            const test = await prisma.user.create({ data: user });
            return test;
        },
    },
```

I was able to run your code as is after this modification.

I would recommend checking out the documentation for express-graphql or some example code to get more familiar with how the library works. [This example](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-express-sdl-first) is a good place to start how to use express, graphql and prisma. It's in typescript but works very similar to what you need.

Comment: Glad to help! 

Please mark the answer as "correct answer" if it answered the question so it is useful to others in the future.